# Using JS In Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars for templating on a simple mobile webpage with [swipejs](http://swipejs.com/).  I made a prototype of the webpage without the templating engine and it worked great.  I then researched the web for a good templating engine and found handlebars.

I embedded the body of my webpage into a script tag, so handlebars can work.  Everything works fine except swipejs (which I'm using for images).

Here's a summarized version of my HTMl:

```
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=no" />
    
    <link media="Screen" href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link media="handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src='scripts/swipe.js'></script>
    <!--[if IEMobile]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <script id="description-script" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <div id="pictures">
        <div id="slider" class="swipe">
            <div class="swipe-wrap">
                <div><center><img style="width:95%;height:auto;" src="image link 1"/></center></div>
                <div><center><img style="width:95%;height:auto;" src="image link 2"/></center></div>
                <div><center><img style="width:95%;height:auto;" src="image link 3"/></center></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Description</h2>
        <div id="description">
            {{description}}
    </div>
</script>
<script>
            //swipe script
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'),
    {
        auto: 3000,
        speed: 300
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance for the help.  Will I have to use a different templating engine or is there something in here that I'm forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to bind the swipe event after the template has been rendered. Or try binding it to the entire 'body' element rather than #slider.

```
 document.getElementById('slider')
```

will fail as it will return null whilst slider sits in the following script tag

```
 <script id="description-script" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

Comment: Did you try binding the swipe after the render? http://jsfiddle.net/nGULk/ This fiddle works for me (excuse the css/styling)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move your `Swipe(...)` code to immedately after you render the `description-script` template in `app.js`.

Something like:

```
// Compile the template
var template = Handlebars.compile($('#description-script').html());

// Render the template
// This makes the #slider DIV appear in the DOM
var data = { description: 'Photos' };
$('body').append(template(data));

// Start Swipe
window.mySwipe = Swipe($('#slider').get(0), {
   auto: 3000,
   speed: 300
});
```

See the following JSFiddle (forked from @TommyBs): http://jsfiddle.net/b4ta3/2/